# Inline UL element not working in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, inline, html-lists

Below is an entire test page that I'm working on (I realize that it is still ugly and cluttered).  My issue is with the ul class="dropdown".  I'm intending on it being a replacement for a SELECT so I can style it (again, not done yet).  However, I cannot seem to position it where I want it.  If you look at this page in FF3.5, that is how I want it to be positioned.  However, in IE7, it is pushing the UL onto the next line instead of butting up against the label.  I've tried numerous hacks that I've found online and none seem to help.  What am I missing here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Radix Test Page</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
            body{
                margin:0;
                padding:1em;    
                font-family:arial,sans-serif;
            }

            .user-form li
            {
                background: #fff none no-repeat bottom right;
                border: 1px solid #000;
                margin: 0;
                padding-right: 35px;
                text-align: right;
            }

            .user-form li label
            {
                background: #fff; 
                border: 1px solid #333;
                display: -moz-inline-stack;    /* Support below FF3 */
                display: inline-block;        /* Used only to set width */
                padding: 1px 0;
                width: 10em;
            }

            .dropdown
            {
                border: 1px solid #f00;
                width: 20em;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                display:inline-block;
            }

            .dropdown , 
            .dropdown ul
            {
                list-style-type:none;
            }

            .dropdown li
            {
                text-align: left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="person.a82c3a5d-5f5e-5dbb-ae3a-14a093157dc2" class="edit-on" action="/service/testclass.php">
            <fieldset>
                <input id="person.a82c3a5d-5f5e-5dbb-ae3a-14a093157dc2:id" name="id" value="a82c3a5d-5f5e-5dbb-ae3a-14a093157dc2" type="hidden"/>
                <ul class="user-form">
                    <li class="valid">
                        <label for="person.a82c3a5d-5f5e-5dbb-ae3a-14a093157dc2:name_prefix">Prefix:</label>
                        <input value="Ms." id="person.a82c3a5d-5f5e-5dbb-ae3a-14a093157dc2:name_prefix" name="name_prefix" type="hidden"/>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="trigger">Miss</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropcontainer">
                                <ul class="dropdownhidden">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">&nbsp;</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Mister</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Misses</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Miss</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Doctor</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">This is just a little test to see exactly how long this silly thing will make my option</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <input name="name_prefix_value" value="Mr." type="hidden"/>
                    </li>
                    <li class="valid">
                        <label for="person.a82c3a5d-5f5e-5dbb-ae3a-14a093157dc2:last_name">Customer Last Name:</label>
                        <input id="person.a82c3a5d-5f5e-5dbb-ae3a-14a093157dc2:last_name" name="last_name" value="Jones" type="text"/>
                    </li>
                    <li class="valid">
                        <label for="person.a82c3a5d-5f5e-5dbb-ae3a-14a093157dc2:first_name">My First Name:</label>
                        <input id="person.a82c3a5d-5f5e-5dbb-ae3a-14a093157dc2:first_name" name="first_name" value="George" type="text"/>
                    </li>
                    <li class="valid">
                        <label for="person.a82c3a5d-5f5e-5dbb-ae3a-14a093157dc2:middle_name">Middle Name:</label>
                        <input id="person.a82c3a5d-5f5e-5dbb-ae3a-14a093157dc2:middle_name" name="middle_name" type="text"/>
                    </li>
                    <li class="valid">
                        <label for="person.a82c3a5d-5f5e-5dbb-ae3a-14a093157dc2:name_suffix">Suffix:</label>
                        <select id="person.a82c3a5d-5f5e-5dbb-ae3a-14a093157dc2:name_suffix" name="name_suffix">
                            <option value="0"/>
                            <option value="Jr.">Junior</option>
                            <option value="Sr.">Senior</option>
                        </select>
                        <input name="name_suffix_value" type="hidden"/>
                    </li>
                    <li class="invalid">
                        <label for="person.a82c3a5d-5f5e-5dbb-ae3a-14a093157dc2:birth_date">Date of Birth:</label>
                        <input id="person.a82c3a5d-5f5e-5dbb-ae3a-14a093157dc2:birth_date" name="birth_date" type="text"/>
                    </li>
                    <li class="warning">
                        <label for="person.a82c3a5d-5f5e-5dbb-ae3a-14a093157dc2:gender">Gender:</label>
                        <select id="person.a82c3a5d-5f5e-5dbb-ae3a-14a093157dc2:gender" name="gender">
                            <option value="0"/>
                            <option value="U">Unknown</option>
                            <option value="M">Male</option>
                            <option value="F">Female</option>
                        </select>
                        <input name="gender_value" type="hidden"/>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="form-actionbar">
                    <input name="form-edit" value="Edit" class="button-view" type="submit" disabled="disabled"/>
                    <input name="form-draft" value="Draft" class="button-edit" type="submit"/>
                    <input name="form-submit" value="Submit" class="button-edit" type="submit"/>
                    <input name="form-cancel" value="CancelMe" class="button-edit" type="submit"/>
                    <input name="form-suspend" value="Suspend" class="button" type="submit"/>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving the hidden input field after the UL?

Comment: Yes, I've moved and removed the hidden inputs but that doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably try putting `<label> and``in two separate``s in a table. Like this:

```
............
    <fieldset>
            <input id="Hidden1" name="id" value="a82c3a5d-5f5e-5dbb-ae3a-14a093157dc2"
                type="hidden" />
            <ul class="user-form">
                <li class="valid">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="vertical-align:bottom">
                                <label for="person.a82c3a5d-5f5e-5dbb-ae3a-14a093157dc2:name_prefix">
                                    Prefix:</label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <ul class="dropdown">
                                    <li><a href="#" class="trigger">Miss</a> </li>
                                    <li class="dropcontainer">
                                        <ul class="dropdownhidden">
                                            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Mister</a> </li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Misses</a> </li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Miss</a> </li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Doctor</a> </li>
                                            <li><a href="#">This is just a little test to see exactly how long this silly thing
                                                will make my option</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <input value="Ms." id="Hidden2" name="name_prefix"
                        type="hidden" />
                    <input name="name_prefix_value" value="Mr." type="hidden" />
                </li>
............
```

Comment: This seems like something I should be able to accomplish with CSS alone.

Answer (score 0):

With IE7, you have to follow any element with the `display: inline-block;` css rule with a `display: inline;` in a subsequent rule, usually found in an "ie lt 7" stylesheet.  Is that possibly what's going on here?